# OS X Keychain: Extracting Private Keys -- possible?

Tags: security, macos, keychain, private-key

I am attempting to extract the raw bytes of a private key stored in a `SecKeyRef` on OS X. How would I go about doing this?

I have read [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/apple-cdsa/2003/Sep/msg00008.html) ~7 year old thread on the Apple CDSA discussion lists, but have found nothing more recent. I am not having the same issue as the original poster in that thread, but it might be on account of me doing the wrong thing. This is what I am currently trying (to no avail):

```
SecKeyRef keyRef = ...;
CSSM_KEY *cssmKey = NULL;
CSSM_WRAP_KEY wrappedKey = {0};

CSSM_CSP_HANDLE cspHandle = 0;
CSSM_CC_HANDLE ccHandle = 0;

CSSM_ACCESS_CREDENTIALS *creds = NULL;
SecKeyGetCredentials(keyRef, CSSM_ACL_AUTHORIZATION_EXPORT_WRAPPED, kSecCredentialTypeDefault, &creds);

// Tried the following, too.
//CSSM_ACCESS_CREDENTIALS *creds = malloc(sizeof(CSSM_ACCESS_CREDENTIALS));
//memset(creds, 0, sizeof(CSSM_ACCESS_CREDENTIALS));

SecKeyGetCSSMKey(keyRef, &cssmKey);
SecKeyGetCSPHandle(keyRef, &cspHandle);

CSSM_CSP_CreateSymmetricContext(cspHandle, 
    CSSM_ALGID_NONE,
    // Have also tried CSSM_ALGMODE_WRAP 
    CSSM_ALGMODE_NONE, 
    creds, 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    CSSM_PADDING_NONE, 
    0, 
    &ccHandle);

CSSM_WrapKey(ccHandle, 
    creds, 
    key, 
    NULL, 
    &wrappedKey);
```

The error code returned by `CSSM_WrapKey` is `CSSMERR_CSP_INVALID_KEYATTR_MASK`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason I have been having issues: the key I was trying to extract had the `CSSM_KEYATTR_SENSITIVE` attributed enabled and I was attempting to perform a "null wrap", i.e. access the unobscured raw bytes.

Lines 285-287 of [libsecurity_apple_csp/lib/wrapKey.cpp](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_apple_csp/libsecurity_apple_csp-36859/lib/wrapKey.cpp) are as follows:

```
if(isNullWrap && (keyAttr & CSSM_KEYATTR_SENSITIVE)) {
    CssmError::throwMe(CSSMERR_CSP_INVALID_KEYATTR_MASK);
}
```

If one has to extract a sensitive private key, it **must** be wrapped -- the default wrapping option for private keys as per the Apple CSP is `CSSM_KEYBLOB_WRAPPED_FORMAT_PKCS8`.

Comment: I think you are setting the CSSM_KEYATTR_SENSITIVE property while importing the private key to keychain right? I have the same issue and I have CSSM_KEYATTR_EXTRACTABLE property set while importing the private key. I am not sure where to set CSSM_KEYBLOB_WRAPPED_FORMAT_PKCS8 property. Also, how do you create "key" parameter for CSSM_WrapKey in the sample app posted by you? Do you have the modified working code with you?